# Unable to determine cause of HTTP 500 in apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have apache httpd 2.4.6 running with a working django application, but occassionally during our nightly test runs, the server returns a 500 error code and I can not figure out why.  There is nothing in the apache error logs indicating a reason.  I have set the LogLevel to 'info' in my apache config (and reloaded apache).  I modified the 'dispatch' method of my view so that it logs the request params to a file.  When a successful POST is done, it logs it just fine, but there is nothing in there for the time when a 500 is returned.  I don't think it's even getting to the django app before returning the 500.

So then I modified by wsgi entry point to be this:

```
class MyWSGIHandler(WSGIHandler):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        print >>environ['wsgi.errors'], pprint.pformat(environ)
        retval = super(MyWSGIHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
        print >>environ['wsgi.errors'], pprint.pformat(retval.__dict__)
        return retval
application = MyWSGIHandler()
```

Again, normally, this will log everything properly to my apache error log, but when the 500 is returned, there's nothing.  The only thing that makes me certain that the request is making it to the server is a line in the apache access log:

[05/Jun/2014:22:41:10 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 600

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Do the errors co-incide with maintenance work? e.g. log rotate is causing an apache reload to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally determined the problem.  I'm using LDAP for authentication and sometimes the ldap server would time out for a user that was not in the LDAP directory.  For whatever reason, this was causing the 500 to be returned.  I have that user defined in a .htdigest file and had set my AuthBasicProvider to "ldap file".  After I switched that around to "file ldap", I haven't seen the problem since.

Answer (score 1):

Django will intercept unhandled exceptions in your code itself and convert them to 500 responses and doesn't propagate the exception up to the WSGI server. Thus neither the WSGI server or your wrapper will see them if that is what is occurring.

You need to configure Django to log details of such errors. One way is to set ADMINS and mail configuration so it can email them to you. The other way is to set up the logging module properly with Django so it will redirect logged messages to stderr and into the Apache error log. Have a look through the Django documentation for more information.

Comment: That was actually the first bit of troubleshooting that I did.  I forgot to mention that in my problem description.  In fact, I intentionally introduced an error in the code for a short time to verify that the email notification and logging was working.

Comment: What is generating the 500 response content then. Is it Apache or Django? Do you happen to have ErrorDocument directives configured in Apache?

Comment: Everything points to it being generated by apache.  I do not have ErrorDocument directives configured.

Comment: If it is Apache, there would generally be some sort of error indicating a problem in the Apache error log. Are there no messages at all for that time period?

Comment: Correct.  There are no messages at all in the error_log for that time period.

Comment: I believe this is actually being caused by the authentication layer.  A timeout to an LDAP server actually.  Closing out this question.  Thanks for your time.